# Hiding an entry from a QMenuBar in Qt4?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4

I can find no non-deprecated way of **hiding an item** in a menu bar in **Qt4**.

This post: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/faqs/585 gives a method that uses deprecated Qt3 compatibility functions.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`QAction::setVisible()`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.0/qaction.html#visible-prop) is what you are looking for:

```
QAction* act = new QAction(tr("&Moo"), this);
someMenu->addAction(act);

// ...

act->setVisible(false);
```

To apply that to menus use their `QAction*` which you get either via [`QMenu::menuAction()`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.0/qmenu.html#menuAction) or from [`QMenu::addMenu()`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.0/qmenu.html#addMenu) (depending on what overload you use).

Comment: I want to remove a *Menu*, not a menu *item*. If I understand correctly, an Action is a menu item, something you can click on directly.

Comment: I thought you wanted to *hide* an *item*? That what your question says. Besides, `addMenu()`  or `QMenu::menuAction()` returns you a `QAction*` which you can use to hide it.

Comment: I said "hide an item in a *MenuBar*", but maybe that wasn't clear enough.


In any case, thanks, I'll look into it.